# WCF - Soap Webservice with Basic Auth, no ssl, self-hosted

Tags: .net, wcf, https, basic-authentication, transport-security

I'm fully aware of the insecurity of this approach, but have a justified need for Basic http authentication for a WCF hosted SOAP webservice. Is there really no way to make this work? Every method I've found of adding basic auth requires transport (https) security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for "TransportCredentialOnly".  See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348328.aspx).

The binding would then look like this:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The above code snippet was taken from [this blog article on the topic](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx).

Comment: I'm actually trying this right now, not working yet but still need to try a couple things. thanks

Comment: Now I'm in business. Strangely, I'd run across this as a solution elsehwere, but everything I read indicated that HTTPS was still required. argh. Thanks man! I have a custom authentication provider now cranking along with this.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got something going!