# WCF wsHttpBinding within the data-centre - typical usage pattern

Tags: .net, wcf, security, architecture, wcf-security

This is something of an architectural question - I hope this is the right stack-exchange for this one - there doesn't seem to be a natural home for these...

The systems I work on are distributed within a data-centre - web-servers in a DMZ then call web-services in a secure zone (through a firewall) for access to data.  This currently uses asmx services with WSE, passing username and password credentials in the SOAP header.  These are passed unencrypted.  The view has been that this provides some measure of security (an attacker on the internet DMZ servers cannot access credentials for services accessed from the intranet DMZ server).

We're looking to move to using WCF, but sticking with webservices.  We'd like to use wsHttpBinding for best interoperability with other clients and for standards compliance.  Continuing to use username authentication this seems to mandate using SSL or message encryption, which is seeming like overkill to a lot of people to be encrypting the connection within our own data-centre where we control both endpoints.

I'd be interested to know if this is what other people do and what alternatives we have.  I've considered (and ruled out a few below)

- SecurityMode = None - don't use any credentials.  Our security people aren't happy with this as attackers on the external web-servers could gain access to any services they like
- Use BasicHttpBinding - I think this can be configured to pass user credentials unencrypted using [TransportCredentialOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788254/wcf-soap-webservice-with-basic-auth-no-ssl-self-hosted) .  However, somewhat concerned that BasicHttpBinding is intended as a legacy approach and less inter-operable with other technologies
- Use the [Clear Username Binding](http://code.google.com/p/wcf-clear-username-binding/) - however, this is open source and my organisation don't want to go near open source for legal reasons
- Accept that we have to move to encrypted messages even within the data-centre
- Change to using a different authentication type e.g. Windows credentials - concern that this is a potentially big change to how we currently operate these services and also whether we have access to a directory server from the DMZ.

Any thoughts on how other people use WCF within a data-centre with security zones would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't really know enough about WCF security to answer all of your questions, but I do know where you can find out!  Check out Chapter 10 of Juval Lowy's Programming WCF services.  That's the WCF bible and Chapter 10 covers everything you ever wanted to know about WCF security.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Funnily enough I have that book already.  IIRC the intranet scenarios assume a 'flat' network with clients and servers all on one network with no firewalls / network zoning etc.  As such using a binding such as netTCP is suggested, not the firewall friendly web-services approach I've inherited.  I'll have a re-read though on Monday (book in my desk drawer at work!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use BasicHttpBinding - I think this can be configured to pass user
>   credentials unencrypted using TransportCredentialOnly . However,
>   somewhat concerned that BasicHttpBinding is intended as a legacy
>   approach and less inter-operable with other technologies

Basic HTTP authentication is the most interoperable built-in authentication mechanism you can use however it sends passwords in a plain text. Also usage can have some little complications if you host your services in IIS and you don't want to use windows accounts for authentication.

> SecurityMode = None - don't use any credentials. Our security people
>   aren't happy with this as attackers on the external web-servers could
>   gain access to any services they like

Securing services in corporate environment is a must.

> Change to using a different authentication type e.g. Windows
>   credentials - concern that this is a potentially big change to how we
>   currently operate these services and also whether we have access to a
>   directory server from the DMZ.

Once you start using Windows credentials you will have to use the same or trusted domains for both networks.

Much better option in this case are Certificates (`CertificateOverTransport` custom security mode). The problem with Basic authentication and UserNameToken authentication in WCF is that user name and password is transported as a plain text. That is also reason why WCF by default (and prior to .NET 4 always) demands encryption either through HTTPS or through message security. Any attacker (including internal attackers which are much more dangerous) can sniff communication either in DMZ or internal network and get all credentials he needs to access your services.

Once you start using certificates the certificate itself with the private key will be securely stored on the server in DMZ - you can even make the certificate non exportable. Once the DMZ application calls your internal service it will add information about the used certificate into SOAP header and signs the timestamp of the message. Anybody can verify the signature (and prove identity of the caller) but only holder of the private key can create one = even if attacker get access to network communication he will not be able to steal the identity. There are other security mechanism related to certificates.

UserNameToken (as you used in WSE) supports encrypted passwords but WCF doesn't have this feature implemented.

To avoid requesting encryption for `UserNameOverTransport` or `CertificateOverTransport` you must [use custom binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725096/how-to-use-message-security-and-username-clientcredentialtype-without-certificat#4725161) (works only in .NET 4 - prior version needs some KB from MS).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer - I haven't fully processed all the info yet, but an initial question on the comments "Securing services in corporate environment is a must" and "Any attacker (including internal attackers which are much more dangerous) can sniff communication either in DMZ or internal network and get all credentials he needs to access your service".  This seems very sensible, but I keep getting funny looks about encrypting within the data-centre.  Any thoughts on if this (encrypting within the data-centre) is normal practice or somewhat unusual?

Comment: That targeted situation when you send credentials in unencrypted message as a plain text. In such case attacker can simply get then and call your service. I'm not sure how common is to encrypt messages inside data-centre but it is absolutely common in a bank even in internal network.